# python - access all dictionary elements not corresponding to key

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to write code to compute pairwise differences in a bunch of data within and between groups. That is, I've loaded the data into a dictionary so that the ith value of data j in group k is accessible by

```
data[j][group[k]][i]
```

I've written for loops to calculate all of the within group pairwise differences, but I'm a little stuck on how to then calculate the between groups pairwise differences. Is there a way to compare all of the values in `data[j][group[k]]` to all of the values in `data[j][*NOT*group[k]]`?
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: It is unclear what the data structure is, and between what exactly you calculate differences. Assuming data[j] is a dict you can get a "sub-dict" with keys != group[k] as dict-comprehension: {d: data[j][d] for d in data[j] if d != group[k]}.

Answer (score 0):

You Could compare them all and then throw out the ones where the group is the same as the one being compared to. (I hope that makes sense)

Or

make a temporary group[l] equal to group[k] minus the instance you are comparing to.